# List of closest annotations in MapKit

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, mapkit

I'm developing an iPhone app with annotations on a map, and I've finished inserting all the annotations. The code I've used for all the annotations (x100) is:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate1;
theCoordinate1.latitude = 59.92855;
theCoordinate1.longitude = 10.80467;

MyAnnotation* myAnnotation1=[[MyAnnotation alloc] init];

myAnnotation1.coordinate=theCoordinate1;
myAnnotation1.title=@"Økern Senter - DNB";
myAnnotation1.subtitle=@"Økernveien 145, 0580 OSLO";

[mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation1];

[annotations addObject:myAnnotation1];
```

What I'm wondering about is how can I get all these locations in a list that shows the closest annotations to the users location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is calculate the distance between the user and the annotations.

First off, in your `MyAnnotation`, add a variable keeping the distance value:
Add the following to `MyAnnotation.h`:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationDistance distance;
```

and the synthesize to the .m file ofcourse.
Second, in your mapView class (the one keeping the annotations ect) add the following code when you recieve a new location:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    [...]
    for (MyAnnotation *annotation in self.mapView.annotations) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [annotation coordinate];
        CLLocation *anotLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coord.latitude longitude:coord.longitude];
        annotation.distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:anotLocation];
    }

    NSArray *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = [self.mapView.annotations sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSNumber *first = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(MyAnnotation*)a distance]];
        NSNumber *second = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(MyAnnotation*)b distance]];
        return [first compare:second];
    }];

    [...]
}
```

You can now use the `sortedArray` as source for a tableView ect, which is sorted according distance from closest to longest distance. 
Of course

Comment: Thanks! Whats the best way to recieve the users location, as you wrote in the second code?

Comment: Using [core location framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html). I added the delegate method for it. However, I do recommend you sepperate the calculation code since the delegate method can return quite often. Maybe you do not want to re-calculate for every cm the user moves.

Comment: Not quite yet :/ I'm a bit of a beginner at Obj-C, do you think you can send me the code for the user location if you can? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help! Just a last question, do you know if Apple will have any problem with using a lot of annotations (200-1000)? Or is this fine as long as I group them together? :)

Comment: I can't say. Only one way to find out, right? I can't imaging they have a problem with it though.